# Problems with MAMP and MacOS Sonoma

Tags: macos, mamp, macos-sonoma

When I installed MAMP, the operating system on my MacBook was Mac OS Monterey. I never updated the OS until today, I went straight to Mac OS Sonoma.
Now when I try to start MAMP it doesn't start and gives me an error:
"Unexpected shutdown of MAMP".

The doubt that came to my mind is that this version of MAMP is not compatible with the new operating system. I think I need to update MAMP, but I don't know how and I'm afraid of losing my data.

Has anyone encountered this problem and/or can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem. May you tell me how you solved it?

Comment: In the end, as written in the comments of the accepted answer, I downloaded the new version of MAMP from the original site, which then automatically overwrote the old version. The installation file can then be deleted. For safety, if you want you can save the DB and project folders (usually "htdocs") somewhere for a backup. For more details read the comments of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonoma broke my installation of MAMP and when I went to install the latest version of MAMP I accidentally downloaded the ARM CPU version. But I have an older Macbook Air with an Intel chip. When I downloaded MAMP for Intel, it worked great.

So make sure you're downloading the right version of MAMP for your processing chip.

Comment: Thanks, I already checked. That's not the problem because it has always worked on my mac (ARM). It only stopped working when I updated OS.

Comment: Then probably you just need to update. Download the newest ARM version and install — you won’t lose data. It will just overwrite the application file, not the accompanying data directories.

Comment: HI! I tried updating the program, and it worked! Projects under the "htdocs" document root are now displayed correctly.
Unfortunately though, there is still a problem. When I enter my project with Laravel 7 through the terminal, I type "php artisan serve" but I get an error: "zsh: command not found: php".

The commands I run are the following:
cd repository,
cd my-project,
php artisan serve.

Same thing, if I try to type "composer install" I get this error: "env: php: No such file or directory".

I hope you can still help me, thank you

Comment: I solved it, I had to update the php version inside the ".zshrc" file.

Comment: Sorry for asking slightly off topic question, will MAMP 4 and 5 still work on Sonoma? I have very old projects which don't have a scope to be updated to latest stack but occasionally features are added to them. So I need to run MAMP 5 and 4 still on Sonoma (to which I shall upgrade once I am sure if it works on). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am running it on my MAC and it's working fine. I'd say to update MAMP and keep it up to date.
From their twitter page: `MAMP & MAMP PRO 6.8.1 are fully compatible with macOS 14 Sonoma!`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to update it. Since I can't find a simple way to do it, what should I do, download the new package again from the original site and it will automatically install the update? I wouldn't want to lose all my databases and data.